# Snake(Game)-like moving rectangles

Tags: java, animation, sprite

I am trying to write some simple snake-game.
For that I've got an ArrayList with Rectangles.
Changing direction already works.

But now, when I add more rectangles (Snake body parts), how can i achieve them to follow the "head"?

I mustn't change the direction of the entire ArrayList, this would end up in some long block moving up or down. It the body should follow the head's movement, go AFTER the head.

How can I achieve that?

That's my not working completely useless update method of the snake...

```
ArrayList<Rectangle> rects;

public void update() {
    if(isMoving && System.currentTimeMillis() - moveTimer > moveSpeed) {
        rects.get(0).setLocation((int)(rects.get(0).getX()+dx*Core.GRID_SIZE), (int)(rects.get(0).getY()+dy*Core.GRID_SIZE));
        for(int i = 0; i < rects.size()-1; i++) {
            if(rects.get(i).getX() < rects.get(i+1).getX()) {
                rects.get(i).setLocation((int)(rects.get(0).getX()+Core.GRID_SIZE), (int)(rects.get(i).getY()));
            }
        }
        moveTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of the code you have already written?

Comment: Head changes its position AFTER giving its old position to next rectangle. Then the rest follow like that. If you want parallelizable code, you should add a position history for each rectangle.

Comment: can we see what you already have? It's unclear what exactly you are stuck at

Answer (score 0):

That's how i solved it: first the last gets the coordinates from the one before last and so on... until the counter reaches 0. The first "head" follows the user input.

Thanks for your contribution!

```
for(int i = rects.size()-1; i > 0; i--) {
            rects.get(i).setLocation((int)(rects.get(i-1).getX()), (int)(rects.get(i-1).getY()));
        }
        rects.get(0).setLocation((int)(rects.get(0).getX()+dx*Core.GRID_SIZE), (int)(rects.get(0).getY()+dy*Core.GRID_SIZE));
```